# How to increase size of column with index

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I want to increase size of my column (NVARCHAR2) from 32 to 64. But I am getting an error:

> ORA-30556: either functional or bitmap join index is defined on the column to be modified

I found solution that I should drop index and then recreate it. But can I do it without doing it? (Maybe disabling and enable, or something like this) because for me it seems that it not make any sense when I am increasing size of column up.

But even when I try do it like I said above, sometimes I am getting another error

> ORA-02429: cannot drop index used for enforcement of unique/primary key

You can strikethrough with the HTML tag  <s>and the close tag</s> .

Like so

<s>I suppose I need to make index unusable and then drop it and recreate all of it. But it seems to be dangerous</s> It seems it is not working even if I would like to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But it seems to be dangerous

Not everything is dangerous.

The first scenario - the one you're dealing with now (increasing column size while there's a functional index on it) - should be OK.

```
SQL> create table test (id varchar2(2));

Table created.
```

Function-based index:

```
SQL> create index i1test on test (upper(id));

Index created.
```

Modifying column size won't work (as you already know):

```
SQL> alter table test modify (id varchar2(5));
alter table test modify (id varchar2(5))
                         *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-30556: either functional or bitmap join index is defined on the column to
be modified
```

So, drop the index / alter table / create index again:

```
SQL> drop index i1test;

Index dropped.

SQL> alter table test modify (id varchar2(5));

Table altered.

SQL> create index i1test on test (upper(id));

Index created.

SQL>
```

Is it *dangerous*? I don't think so. Performance might suffer if table doesn't have index. If table is *huge*, then it'll take time to recreate the index, but - apart from performance - I guess it is OK.

---

Note, though, that function-based index can't be used to enforce that constraint:

```
SQL> create table test (id varchar2(2));

Table created.

SQL> create index i1test on test (upper(id));

Index created.

SQL> alter table test add constraint pk_test primary key (id) using index i1test;
alter table test add constraint pk_test primary key (id) using index i1test
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-14196: Specified index cannot be used to enforce the constraint.


SQL>
```

---

However, when we're at index which is used to enforce primary key constraint, then yes - it might be dangerous because

- primary key also enforces *uniqueness* so - if you drop it - someone might be able to insert/update table and violate uniqueness
- primary key might be referenced by one (or more) foreign key constraints. You can't drop the primary key constraint while foreign keys exist because of

  ```
  ORA-02273: this unique/primary key is referenced by some foreign keys
  ```

  so you'd first have to drop foreign key constraints (you can't just *disable* them), which also lets someone enter invalid values into that/those column(s)

Therefore, it just depends on current situation. Sometimes it is simpler, sometimes it is complex and the way you'd deal with it depends on complexity.

---

BTW, do you **really** have to drop index used for the primary key constraint if you're modifying column's size? No:

```
SQL> create table test (id varchar2(2));

Table created.

SQL> create index i1test on test (id);

Index created.

SQL> alter table test add constraint pk_test primary key (id) using index i1test;

Table altered.

SQL> alter table test modify (id varchar2(5));

Table altered.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems clearer know. But I dont understand last part. Why is it `alter table test add constraint pk_test primary key (id) using index i1test;` allowing me to alter table, even when above you showed it is not possible without this line?

Comment: This ALTER TABLE just adds the primary key constraint on the TEST table, and PK constraint uses index which already exists on the ID column. Could've been way simpler, e.g. `create table test (id varchar2(2) primary key);` and Oracle would create primary key constraint and (in the *background*) index which will support it).